# How to get the max constant buffer size with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

In my application, I want to get the max constant buffer size. With DX, there is a macro `D3D10_REQ_CONSTANT_BUFFER_ELEMENT_COUNT` represents this value.

How can I get this value with `OpenGL`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL has no such limitation.

[Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) can be of arbitrary sizes. However, different *uses* of buffer objects have different size limitations. The [source for vertex array data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) is essentially unbounded. But [buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture#Limitations) have a size limit. The size of a [bound range of uniform buffer data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object#Limitations) has a limit. And [various other uses](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use) have limits, as needed. But there is no limit on the size of the memory buffer *itself*.

Basically, think of buffer objects as pointers to GPU memory, with `glBufferData` as `malloc`. Different APIs that use pointers can have limits on how much memory they can access. But `malloc` *itself* doesn't have any particular limits (besides running out of memory, of course).

Comment: Thanks, I was little confused about the concepts, your answer helps a lot. I just realized that the "const buffer" in dx corresponds to the "Uniform Block" in OGL, so I can use glGetIntegerv() method and GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_BLOCKS, GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_UNIFORM_BLOCKS, GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_BLOCKS, GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE to get the properties.